# Displaying incomplete values from database, when value has single quote,

Tags: php, mysql, forms

When i query from the database, for example a product, "men's banana" it only shows "men" it cuts of the rest of the text. the issue only happens when i query it inside the text area, but when i query it straight from the database it shows the complete text.

When using the textarea form type, it shows them all even with the single quote. however when displaying it inside this form it cuts of the rest.

```
echo "<td><label for='prod_price'>Product Name:</label></td>
      <td><input name='prod_name' id='prod_name' type='text' class='col1' value='$prodname'></td>
      </tr>";
```

what should i do to fix this problem. i cant think of a proper question to search google. so i explained it here.

here are the rest of my codes the un necessary ones are removed

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Edit a Product</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cms.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>
    <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#prod_brand").autocomplete("prod_brand_auto_complete.php", {
            selectFirst: true
      });
     });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
  <style>
button {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
a{
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

</style>


<?php
session_start();
  $conn = @mysql_connect("localhost","root","12148qx3er");
  $db = @mysql_select_db("buybranded");
$itemid = $_GET['id'];
$qry = "SELECT * FROM inventory where prod_id = ".$itemid;
mysql_set_charset("UTF8");
$result = @mysql_query($qry);
if($result === FALSE) {
    die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
}


echo "<div id='page-wrap'>
  <h1>Edit a Product</h1>";
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

$prodbrand = $row['prod_brand'];
$prodname = $row['prod_name'];
$prodcategory = $row['prod_category'];
$prodprice = $row['prod_price'];
$prod_desc = $row['prod_desc'];
$prodpic = $row['prod_pic'];
$prodquantity = $row['prod_quantity'];

echo "<form enctype='multipart/form-data' method='post' action='updating_inv.php?id=$itemid'>";
echo "<table>
      <tr>";
echo "<td><label for='prod_brand'>Product Brand:</label></td>
      <td><input name='prod_brand' id='prod_brand' type='text' class='col1' placeholder='Auto Complete Form' value='$prodbrand'/></td>";

echo "<td><label for='prod_price'>Product Name:</label></td>
      <td><input name='prod_name' id='prod_name' type='text' class='col1' value='$prodname'></td>
      </tr>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><label for='prod_price'>Product Price:</label></td>
      <td><input name='prod_price' id='prod_price' type='text' class='col1' value='$prodprice'/></td>";
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td><label for='prod_desc'>Description:</label></td>
        <td><textarea name='prod_desc' id='prod_desc' class='col2'>$prod_desc</textarea></td>";

  echo "<td></td><td><table><tr>";

  echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . base64_encode( $row['prod_pic'] ) . '" width="100" border="1px"/><br>';
  echo "<td><label for='prod_pic'>Upload Image:</label><br><input type='file' name='prod_pic' class='col2' value=''/></td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td><label for='prod_quantity'>Quantity:</label><br><input name='prod_quantity' id='prod_quantity' type='text' class='col2' placeholder='ex. 10' value='$prodquantity'/></td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td><form method='post'><button>Update this Entry!</button>";
  echo "<button><a href='inventory.php'>Go back</a></button></td>"; 
  echo "</tr></table></td></table>";

  echo "</form>";






  }
  echo "</div>";
?>

    </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your input element:

```
<input name='prod_name' id='prod_name' type='text' class='col1' value='$prodname'>
```

When you select data from DB, and prodname is lets say:

```
$prodname="12'3"
```

After substitution your input element will be:

```
<input name='prod_name' id='prod_name' type='text' class='col1' value='12'3'>
```

Can you see now why it doesn't work?

Also please keep in mind, it can be serious security issue. See what will happen when prodname is something evil, like:

```
$prodname="' onclick='...some malicious js...' '"
```

echo will send:

```
<input name='prod_name' id='prod_name' type='text' class='col1' value='' onclick='...some malicious js...' ''>
```

Good idea is to escape every string BEFORE db insertion using **mysql_real_escape_string()**. Don't use addslashes nor htmlentities for this.

So when you insert/update, escape strings with mysql_real_escape_string() to avoid SQL injection etc. Something like this should work:

```
mysql_query("insert into invertory (prod_brand, prod_name) values (".mysql_real_escape_string($prodbrand).", ".mysql_real_escape_string.")")
```

Or you can escape all strings in a loop or so.

Later when you select data and echo HTML, the only character you have to escape to keep HTML consistent is in your case an apostrophe. So on every string you have to translate it to something web browser can still understand - HTML code (for apostrophe is `&#39;`):

```
echo "<input name='prod_name' value='".strtr($prodname, array("'"=>'&#39;'))."'>"
```

Comment: I see, thank you for your well explained answer. Now i understand why it doesnt work. 

so how do i use the mysql_real_escape_string()? im new with php

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using PHP's PDO Class (prepared statements). The PDO Class is handling special characters of queries automatically: http://php.net/manual/it/book.pdo.php

The error you're getting, is probably happening, because the special characters are messing up your query:

> SELECT * FROM test WHERE a LIKE 'men's banana'

The single quote should be escaped, to get the query working correctly:

> SELECT * FROM test WHERE a LIKE 'men\'s banana'

As previously stated, PDO is doing that for you.
It's also a big security problem, once your Webpage is online (SQL Injection).

The problem is also the same, when you print your response. Giving the value to the textbox messes up the attribute:

> <input type='text' value='men's banana' />

Just use the normal quotes instead:

> <input type="text" value="men's banana" />

Answer (score 0):

You can use several functions for that. Check https://php.net/htmlentities and http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php. Both of them should do the trick.

An example use of htmlentities() in your code:

```
echo "<td><label for='prod_brand'>Product Brand:</label></td>
  <td><input name='prod_brand' id='prod_brand' type='text' class='col1' placeholder='Auto Complete Form' value='" . htmlentities($prodbrand, ENT_QUOTES) . "'/></td>";
```

An example use of addslashes() in your code:

```
echo "<td><label for='prod_brand'>Product Brand:</label></td>
  <td><input name='prod_brand' id='prod_brand' type='text' class='col1' placeholder='Auto Complete Form' value='" . addslashes($prodbrand) . "'/></td>";
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: So what does it do? Can you explain it to me? What happens when i use it?

Answer (score 0):

You can write [echo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) like this way

```
 echo <<<HTML
     <tr>
     <td><label for="prod_price">Product Name:</label></td>
     <td><input name="prod_name" id="prod_name" type="text" class="col1" value="$prodname"></td>
     </tr>
HTML;
```